# Terraform Interpolation/Expressions v0.12

Tags: terraform

So after upgrading from Terraform v0.11.4 to v0.12.5 I have hit a know "bug" as detailed in Hashicorps ticket #21411 around referring to list variables and the use of the flatten function to manage this.

I have converted a few attribute values using the flatten function as described in the Hashicorp upgrade notes but this one has beaten me so far:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  count = local.nat_gw_count

  allocation_id = element(aws_eip.nat_gw.*.id, count.index)
  subnet_id = element(data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.subnet_ids_frontend, count.index)
  tags = merge(
    local.default_tags,
    {
     "Name" = "${var.project}_${var.env}_natgw_${count.index}"
    },
  )
}
```

The returned error message is:

```
   Error: Incorrect attribute value type

   on nat_gw.tf line 56, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "public":
   56:   subnet_id = element(data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.subnet_ids_proxy, count.index)

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.
```

The value stored in the remote state is as follows:

```
subnet_ids_frontend = [
  [
    "subnet-03b44ca6123456789",
    "subnet-02e6bf55123456789",
  ],
]
```

The subnet_id format has been updated by the terraform upgrade script but as the docs mention its a little hit and miss in this area.

Any ideas what the correct format/function to use here is?

Comment: Your `subnet_ids_frontend` is a nested list and not a list, so you have to access the list with the first element and then the string with the second element, i.e. `data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.subnet_ids_frontend[0][count.index]`. Alternatively, store the value as a list instead of a nested list and that would also work.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, good call. I had noticed that this remote state output seems to be littered with lists of lists but this is the first time it has been an issue. I was stuck thinking I had to use element to get the elements out. I would mark this as the answer but it is a comment, do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subnet_ids_frontend` variable stored in the remote state is a nested list of two dimensions. Therefore, you need to access the nested list with the first element and then the string with the second element. This would be done via `data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.subnet_ids_frontend[0][<subnet_id_element>]` (note this utilizes Terraform 0.12 first class expressions for variables). The code update for your resource would be:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
  count = local.nat_gw_count

  allocation_id = element(aws_eip.nat_gw.*.id, count.index)
  subnet_id     = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.subnet_ids_frontend[0][count.index]
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, the `subnet_ids_frontend` value stored in the remote state could be constructed as a list instead of a nested list, and then no code update would be necessary.